# How can I have rails select for update on multiple rows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, pessimistic-locking

I can't figure out how to tell rails to `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` on multiple rows. Poking around in console, `Foo.where(bar: "baz").lock` does produce the right SQL. But when I try to do it in a transaction, that ruby code doesn't actually generate the SQL. I think the one-off is working because the rails console automatically runs `.all` on the relation to display the results.

Here's what I run in console

```rb
Foo.transaction do
  Foo.where(bar: "baz").lock  
  Foo.where(bar: "baz").update_all(bar: "baz2")  
end
```

and the SQL:

```sql
BEGIN
  Foo Update All (0.5ms)  UPDATE "foos" SET "bar" = $1 WHERE "foos"."bar = $1 [["bar", "baz2"]]
COMMIT
```

If I change the lock line so that rails thinks that it needs to do somthing with the collection, like add `puts` to the beginning or `pluck` to the end...

```rb
Foo.where(bar: "baz").lock.pluck(:id)
```

...then I do get the expected `FOR UPDATE` query before the update happens, with the expense of having to pipe the result over the wire and put it into memory and then do nothing with it.

So it seems that rails properly uses `.lock` to modify the SQL of the relation, but there's no elegant way to actually invoke the lock. Am I doing something wrong or do we need to use some sort of workaround (like `pluck`) to get the query to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspired by discussion here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/257188/

I think the best general purpose solution is

```rb
Foo.where(bar: "baz").order(:id).lock.pluck('')
```

Which will produce

```sql
SELECT  FROM "foos" WHERE "foos"."bar" = 'baz' ORDER BY "foos"."id" ASC FOR UPDATE;
```

Comment: Update - I'm not sure what changed since I first experimented with this but it either was never working or or some reason stopped working in my project. YMMV -comment if it did or didn't work for you

Answer (score 4):

```rb
ApplicationRecord.transaction do
  User.where(id: [1, 2]).lock!.map do |user|
    puts user.id
    user.id
  end
end
```

produces

```
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IN (1, 2) FOR UPDATE
1
2
   (0.9ms)  COMMIT
=> [1, 2]
```

Comment: @JohnBachir This is just example, that action in block is protected by `SELECT FOR UPDATE`.

Comment: @JohnBachir May be I didn't get your initial question. What you are looking for?

Comment: I asked this question over on DBA: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/257188/

Comment: @JohnBachir `UPDATE` will auto lock the records - as noted in first comment @  dba.stackexchange. And my answer there was about "How can I have rails select for update on multiple rows".