# Is there any way to select an ActiveRecord relation for update?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In Rails 6.1 I would like to select a relation for update (lock the rows inside a transaction).

```
Foo.transaction do
  # this is foos_query in raw sql
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute <<~SQL
    SELECT FROM "foos"
    WHERE
      type = 'bar' AND
      associated_object = '#{thing_id}' AND
      other_party_id = '#{user_id}'
    ORDER BY id
    FOR UPDATE
  SQL
  foos_query.update_all(read: "true", seen: true)
end
```

In previous versions of rails, I *think* this could be hacked with `foos_query.lock.pluck('')`, but it stopped working at some point.

Is there a supported or hacky way to do this without raw sql?

related:

- [How can I have rails select for update on multiple rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59668945/how-can-i-have-rails-select-for-update-on-multiple-rows)
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/257188/how-can-i-lock-rows-for-update-without-returning-data-over-the-connection

Comment: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html

Comment: @muistooshort i think there's no way to do it on the entire relation without loading the AR objects into memory

Answer (score 0):

I went with

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute foos_query.order(:id).lock.to_sql
```

see also

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/257188

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/257217